# How to std::swap elements in a container safely

Tags: c++, std, swap

I have this situation in my program that I want to iterate inside `std::vector` which has a type of `swcObject*` (abstract base class) with the use of `std::iterators`.

Code:

```
class swcObject    // abstract class
{
protected:
    // inheritable members
    // some are pure virtual functions()
    // ...
public:
    int x, y, width, height;
    // getter/setter
private:
    // implicit task()
}

std::vector<swcObject*> objects;

void other::OnClickSwapObject()
{

    for (auto i = objects.rbegin(); i != objects.rend(); ++i)
    {
        if ((*i)->isClick(MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT))
        {
            std::swap(*i, *objects.begin()); // is this the right syntax to do it?
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am confused a bit if I should use `std::reverse_iterator` and use `std::vector::begin()` or `std::vector::end()` in `std::swap(x)` since adding elements on `std::vector<swcObject*> objects` is through backwards(?).
Its working but is my code safe for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `i` is a reverse iterator makes no difference. If you want to swap the value at `i` with the first value of the vector, you should do what you are doing. Also note that the iterator returned by `end()` is after the last element in the vector and should never be dereferenced.

Comment: If I have only two elements, is `object.begin()` and `object.end()` points to those two elems? How can I safely swap with this two values?

Comment: @mr5 No, `end()` does not point to any element, it is a placeholder for the element after the last element. See the picture [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end). To swap the two values you could do `std::swap(object.front(), object.back())` or `std::swap(object[0], object[1])` or `std::swap(*object.begin(), *(object.begin() + 1))`.

Comment: ahh thanks for the link...I just figure out another good idea...**I will get the last element and swap it to the current one**

Comment: But I'm not sure about the `(preferred || right) && safe` syntax to do it